# Countif with case sensitive google-sheets

Tags: google-sheets, case, countif

I'm trying to do a case-sensitive count in Google Sheets.

For example, I have these values :

```
A
A
A
B
a
b
```

The countif function :
=COUNTIF(A1:A6;"A") give me 4 whereas I expected to have the number 3

All results :

| Letter/Word | Number give by countif | Expected number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 4 | 3 |
| a | 4 | 1 |
| b | 2 | 1 |
| B | 2 | 1 |

How could I create a case-sentive countif ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to achieve that. Here's one way:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(REGEXMATCH(A1:A6, "A"))
```

Or, depending on your locale:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(REGEXMATCH(A1:A6; "A"))
```

Comment: I don't know what your locale is, as you didn't share a sheet but some locales use semi-colons in formulas. I updated my answer.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WlcqEjMXOKKnJUZ6kkSGxn3NQdSVjNIqS--qQsdhGwA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Most welcome, @JulesMassart. If this solved your issue, please upvote or accept the answer (see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Cheers !

Comment: This works in a single cell, but what if I need to use this inside of an ARRAYFORMULA? For example, if I need to match column B to anything in column A. Using this single cell example, the equivalent would be `=SUMPRODUCT( REGEXMATCH( $A$1:$A$6, B1 ) )` and $A$1:$A$6 would be static - always the same range, but B1 would change to B2, B3, B4, B5, B6 as the formula is copied down the rows. If I use ARRAYFORMULA and do `=ARRAYFORMULAT( SUMPRODUCT( REGEXMATCH($A$1:$A$6, $B1:$B6) ) )` then it's going to compare A1 to B1, A2 to B2, etc... when I want to compare A1:A6 to B1 and A1:A6 to B2, etc...